# IntelliJ Undeploy Project on Startup on Weblogic 12

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, deployment, weblogic

I am working on a legacy code and I must deploy project on Weblogic server because of JNDI connections. Everything is  work fine but project deploys twice on startup. I think IntelliJ deploys project after Weblogic server startup deploys. This problem slows us down. I found some solution on linux machines but I need a solution on windows.

The solution I found : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-58796

**IntelliJ version:** 2023.1.1

**WebLogic version:** 12c

**JDK :** 1.8

Comment: You can try to configure the server so that it doesn't deploy anything on start. Start the server outside of IntelliJ IDEA to verify that nothing is deployed. One more possible solution https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000129390/comments/4403071761042